# How do I fix "Error parsing XML: unclosed token (APT0000)" ? (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

So Im currently trying to figure out how to work with platform specific code. iOS works just fine. But Android is making me problems and I dont know how to fix it.

When running the same code on an iOS emulator my code works but running the same code on an Android Emulator it gives me the error "Error parsing XML: unclosed token (APT0000)". Does anyone know why it happens and how to fix this?

xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="BookCodeSL.PlatInfoSap1">


    <StackLayout Padding="20">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Device Model:"/>

            <ContentView Padding="50,0,0,0">
                <Label x:Name="modelLabel"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Operating System Version:"/>

            <ContentView Padding="50,0,0,0">
                <Label x:Name="versionLabel"
                       FontSize="Large"
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
            </ContentView>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

cs:

```
//...
#elif __ANDROID__
using Android.OS;

//...

    public partial class PlatInfoSap1 : ContentPage
    {
        public PlatInfoSap1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

#if __IOS__

            UIDevice device = new UIDevice();
            modelLabel.Text = device.Model.ToString();
            versionLabel.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", device.SystemName, device.SystemVersion);

#elif __ANDROID__
            modelLabel.Text = String.Format("{0} {1}", Build.Manufacturer, Build.Model);


  versionLabel.Text = Build.VERSION.Release.ToString();

#endif
    }
}
```

*edit*

The error can be found in

abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml

this is the code to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND
```

Comment: Is the XAML for your page complete? If yes, then you are missing the closing `</ContentPage>` tag.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis the `</ContentPage>` tag is included in the question, but not visibible because of wrong code formatting. It appears when you hit the `edit` button.

Comment: This error appears when your xml tags aren't closed correctly.

Comment: The end tag is not missing in my code. pfx is right. I failed at the code formatting here. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you missing some codes in the `abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml`?

It should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2014 The Android Open Source Project
     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at
          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/bright_foreground_disabled_material_light"/>
    <item android:color="@color/bright_foreground_material_light"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: Hi. I just tried this. It still does not work. Same error :(

Comment: @axbeit Is the error only can be found in `abc_primary_text_disable_only_material_light.xml`? Is there any other xml file that get the same error? Try to  delete the .bin and .obj folder under you Android project, and then clean and rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your XML is not a valid XML.
Please make sure that you close every XML property, for example, the most obvious in your XML file the

```
<ContentPage ...>
...
</ContentPage>
```

This can help you with that, https://www.xmlvalidation.com/

Comment: The end tag is included in my xaml. It just didnt appear here in stackoverflow due to me failing to format my code correctly. Sorry.